# Fix for 'Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError: Illformed requirement [">=1 <2"]' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpacker

How do I fix this error when deploying a rails 6 application to heroku?
(It has spree gem installed)

```
      rake aborted!
       Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError: Illformed requirement [">=1 <2"]
       /tmp/build_d17738d2f38bed1a2488535e1dbef5b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-07a62a9dfed3/lib/tasks/webpacker/check_yarn.rake:11:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d17738d2f38bed1a2488535e1dbef5b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-07a62a9dfed3/lib/tasks/webpacker/check_yarn.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_d17738d2f38bed1a2488535e1dbef5b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-07a62a9dfed3/lib/tasks/webpacker/compile.rake:14:in `block in enhance_assets_precompile'
       /tmp/build_d17738d2f38bed1a2488535e1dbef5b9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => webpacker:compile => webpacker:verify_install => webpacker:check_yarn
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

What caused it:

Adding

```
gem 'spree', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.6'
```

How I worked my way around it:

```
mv Gemfile.lock /tmp/
bundle install
mv yarn.lock /tmp/
yarn install --check-files
```

Btw I'm on

```
Rails 6.0.2.1
ruby 2.7.0p0
Bundler version 2.1.2
yarn 1.17.3
```

Hope this helps someone.